# Crashing/error on opening SQLite database in UWP/C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to add code to an old UWP app to access an SQLite database. It works fine when debugging in VisualStudio but when I package it for sideloading it breaks.

I've shrunk it down and tried to simplify the code to see if there's any issues. Below is a small bit of code I'd put in to test out what is going on. The code breaks on opening the database. Again, this works fine when debugging in Visual Studio and breaks when sideloaded.

```
string entry = "";
string dbpath = @"S:\TestDB.db");
using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
{
    db.Open();
    string textCommand = "SELECT Source from Materials WHERE Material = @keyValue";
    SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand(textCommand, db);
    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyValue", "PMMA");
    SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (query.Read()) { entry = query.GetString(0); }
    db.Close();
}
return entry;
```

Does anyone have anything I can try out?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Do you have an sqlite file without any extention? Do both Dev and Test System have Drive "S" ?

Comment: The SQLite file has an extension, I just missed that when adding it on here. All the computers have access. Just to test I sideloaded it on the Dev system and still the same issue.

Comment: It is throwing an SqliteException of some kind. I'm not sure how I can find more information as it works fine when debugging.

Comment: can you not log the error? or if you're not handling the exception, the crash log should be in event viewer

Comment: Time to learn about Logging-Frameworks ;)

Comment: SQLite Error 14: 'Unable to open database file'

Is there a way I can get more info out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone else who had a similar problem while searching for the answer to my question. I messaged them and they told me to put:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="developmentModeNetwork" />
```

in my manifest.

Seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Crashing/error on opening SQLite database in UWP/C#,'Unable to open database file' Is there a way I can get more info out of it.

I'm afraid you can't access db file where in the `S` disk with path directly. In UWP it only has permission access local folder with path. So we suggest you place your db file into [`LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder?view=winrt-22000) like this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases).

```
string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sqliteSample.db");
    using (SqliteConnection db =
      new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
```

Comment: But it works when debugging in visual studio. I can't see anywhere that says you can't access a file outside of the local folder? Could you point me to the documentation that says that? I have given the app file system access.

Comment: Please refer to File access [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) document.

Comment: you could  access a file outside of the local folder, but  uwp app run in sandbox, so we need fileopenpicker to access file  or add `broadFileSystemAccess` and access the file with path by windows storage api

Comment: I did give it broadfilesystemaccess which is what is confusing me.

Comment: Yep, I know that, please check the above document `broadfilesystemaccess`  only avaiable for Windows storage api, but `SqliteConnection` looks like use `system.io` api to read file. that's why  broadfilesystemaccess not work for `SqliteConnection`